# unable to install bigfloat in osx, command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, xcode, macos

I'm trying to install bigfloat in OSX Sierra with:

```
pip install bigfloat
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
    mpfr.c:343:10: fatal error: 'gmp.h' file not found
    #include "gmp.h"
             ^
    1 error generated.
    error: command 'clang' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/pip-build-adS6t_/bigfloat/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/pip-fwI1xE-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hd/96gvrtvn66dcnbntwn9v3skh0000gp/T/pip-build-adS6t_/bigfloat/
```

I already installed Xcode and ran:

```
xcode-select --install
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing GMP, if you use brew make sure to install both GMP and MPFR with `brew install gmp mpfr`, they're both prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else with the issue, this worked for me:

```
brew install gmp mpfr
env "CFLAGS=-I/opt/homebrew/include -L/opt/homebrew/lib" pip install bigfloat
```